# What is the impact of outside scaling on the heat exchanger of a tankless water heater?

Tags: water-heater, tankless

- live in the mountains. hard water.
- i descale 1-2 times a year.
- still, there is visual evidence of scaling on the outside of the heat exchange. proximate to the bottom gasket and the glass-window.

what will be the impact of this? will the system fail because of this scaling?

[image: scaling on outside of heat exchanger]

Comment: none other than cosmetic, or maybe accelerated rusting

Comment: That's not scaling, unless you have a leak here.  That's corrosion, look at installation conditions.

Comment: thanks @Ruskes and Harper. you're probably right. there is no leakage, thus likely external corrosion. if either of you want to add an answer, I'll give you a couple of days before I answer it myself to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By performing close evaluation, you can determine is it scaling or corrosion.

If it is scaling you have a leak somewhere.

Usually the corrosion is also accelerated by humidity/leak.

If you are absolutely sure there is no leak, clean up the corroded area, and then you can apply some anicorosion preventer to reduce the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Yours looks a lot worse than mine, and mine didn't even last 2 years. The heat exchanger corroded and got a pin hole leak. Navien warrantied the exchanger but paid $700 for the install. They won't let you do it yourself. The new exchanger is a year old now and looks to be scaling. You can look in the heat exchanger if you remove the plate next to the electrode on the top right hand corner. Just remove the 2 Phillips screws. Be careful not to puncture the flame proof material like I did. Had to cover it back up with tin foil. The new one has a clear window so you can see the flame. Been trying to figure out why it corrodes so fast.